# How to use Windows User Login to authenticate with Webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, authentication, active-directory

I have a client-server application (both Windows, client is WPF, non-UWP) and i want to do authentication via active directory. My idea is to take the credentials (or a token) from the windows machine that the client is on and send that information to the server (via webservice, IIS, asp.net). the server then checks with ad if the credentials are valid and does authorization...
So the key points would be:

- extract credentials/token from client-windows
- send it via vebservice to server (that part should be simple)
- validation on server against active directory

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Look at the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for a windows user authentication in a desktop application you can simpy use the

```
Environment.UserName
```

Variable, it provides the username of the current logged in user.
if you want to check if it is an active directory user you can call a function like this:

```
public bool UserExists(string username)
{
   // create your domain context
   using (PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
   {
       // find the user
       UserPrincipal foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, IdentityType.Name, username);

       return foundUser != null;
    }
}
```

### With your new request you can split the code above:

In the client you can get the AD username and domain using `Environment` variable, pass it to the server and check if the user exist using the `UserExist()` function

Comment: To improve your answer, copy the relevant parts from the link to your answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this describes how to implement using windows credentials in a website hosted in IIS from the browser. It does not seem to show, what I would have to do in my client application to leverage this feature and I doubt that this will "just work".